# Query DynamoDB based on whether attribute is member of a group

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

This is a simplified version of my problem using a DynamoDB Table. Most items in the Table represent sales across multiple countries.  One of my required access patterns is to retrieve all sales in countries which belong to a certain `country_grouping` between a range of `order_date`s.  The incoming stream of sales data contains the `country` attribute, but not the `country_grouping` attribute.

Another entity in the same Table is a reference table, which is infrequently updated, which could be used to identify the `country_grouping` for each `country`. Can I design a GSI or otherwise structure the table to retrieve all sales for a given `country_grouping` between a range of order dates?

Here's an example of the Table structure:

| PK | SK | sale_id | order_date | country | country_grouping |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SALE#ID#1 | ORDER_DATE#2022-06-01 | 1 | 2022-06-01 | UK |  |
| SALE#ID#2 | ORDER_DATE#2022-09-01 | 2 | 2022-09-01 | France |  |
| SALE#ID#3 | ORDER_DATE#2022-07-01 | 3 | 2022-07-01 | Switzerland |  |
| COUNTRY_GROUPING#EU | COUNTRY#France |  |  | France | EU |
| COUNTRY_GROUPING#NATO | COUNTRY#UK |  |  | UK | NATO |
| COUNTRY_GROUPING#NATO | COUNTRY#France |  |  | France | NATO |

**Possible solution 1**

As the sales items are streamed into the Table, query the `country_grouping` associated with the `country` in the sale, and write the corresponding `country_grouping` to each sale record.  Then create a GSI where `country_grouping` is the partition key and the `order_date` is the sort key. This seems expensive to me, consuming 1 RCU and 1 WCU per sale record imported.  If country groupings changed (imagine the UK rejoins the EU), then I would run an update operation against all sales in the UK.

**Possible solution 2**

Have the application first query to retrieve every `country` in the desired `country_grouping`, then send an individual request for each country using a GSI where the partition key is `country` and the `order_date` is the sort key.  Again, this seems less than ideal, as I consume 1 WCU per country, plus the 1 WCU to obtain the list of countries.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picking an optimal solution depends on factors you haven't mentioned:

- How quickly you need it to execute
- How many sales records per country and country group you insert
- How many sales records per country you expect there to be in the db at query time
- How large a Sale item is

For example, if your Sale items are large and/or you insert a lot every second, you're going to need to worry about creating a hot key in the GSI. I'm going to assume your update rate is not too high, the Sale item size isn't too large, and you're going to have thousands or more Sale items per country.

If my assumptions are correct, then I'd go with Solution 2. You'll spend one read unit (it's not a WCU but rather an RCU, and it's only half a read unit if eventually consistent) to Query the country group and get a list of countries. Do one Query for each country in that group to pull all the Sale items matching the specific time range for that country. Since there are lots of matching sales, the cost is about the same. One 400 KB pull from a country_grouping PK is the same cost as 4 100 KB pulls from four different country PKs. You can also do the country Query calls in parallel, if you want, to speed execution. If you're returning megabytes of data or more, this will be helpful.

If in fact you have only a few sales per country, well, then any design will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution 1 is probably best. The underlying issue is that PK actually defines the physical location on a server (both for an original entry or a GSI copy). You duplicate data because storage is cheap to get better performance for queries.

So if like you said UK rejoins UE, you won't be modifying the entries for GSI, AWS will create a new entry in a different location since PK changed.

Comment: Thanks karjan, I suspected this was true.  I just hoped there might be a tricky way of fulfilling the access pattern without the additional read and write steps.

Answer (score 0):

How about if you put the country_grouping in the SK of the sale?

For example `COUNTRY_GROUPING#EU#ORDER_DATE#2022-07-01`

Then you can do a "begins with" query and avoid the GSI which will consume the extra capacity unit.

The country group lookup can be cached in memory to save some units + I wouldn't design my table around one-time events like the UK leaving. If that happens do a full scan and update everything. It's a one-time operation, not a big deal.
Also, Dynamo is not designed to store items for large periods of time. Typically you would store the sales for the past 30 days (for example) set e TTL to the items and stream them to S3 (or BigQuery) once they expire.

Comment: That still leaves us with the same issue. Streams have to be used to create that additional field `COUNTRY_GROUPING#EU#ORDER_DATE#2022-07-01` and you need to modify it if grouping changes. 

But why are you saying DynamoDB is not designed to store items for large periods of time? That's not true, it's scalable performant and cheap.

Comment: If you keep the data smaller operational costs are a lot smaller. Older data is usually kept for business analysis purposes, and the best place to store such data is in a data warehouse, Of course, that might not be the case for you, however, all of your concerns are neglible for small data sets. How many sale entires do you expect per day?

Comment: I'm expecting about 50,000 sales entries per day.

Comment: And for how long do you need to keep each sale entry in order for the application to work properly?

Comment: If you store all of this data for business analysis purposes only. Consider Amazon Redshift or BigQuery
https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/

Comment: If I got it right, the case is about storage. OP does not need complex queries. Redshift would be an overkill